# Change Python if input to be case insensitive

Tags: python

I'm in school, and since we are rather young students, some of my 'colleagues' do not grasp what case sensitivity is. We are making a quiz in Python. Here is the code:

```
score = 0 #this defines variable score, and sets it as zero
print("What is the capital of the UK?")
answer = input ()
if answer == "London":
    print("Well done")
    score = score + 1 #this increases score by one
else:
   print("Sorry the answer was London")
   print("What is the capital of France?")
answer = input ()
if answer == "Paris":
    print("Well done")
    score = score + 1 #this increases score by one
else:
    print("Sorry the answer was Paris")
    print("Your score was ",score)
```

They are inputting 'london' as an answer instead of 'London' and still getting the answer wrong. Any workaround?

Comment: I would argue that "london" is incorrect. As any young student should know, proper nouns begin with a capital letter ;-)

Also, you will need to unindent the line that prints "What is the capital of France?"

Comment: The last call to `print` also needs to be unindented.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.upper()` or `.lower()`

```
if answer.lower() == 'london':
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string1.lower() on answer and you can then make a variable for London and it string1.lower().

example:

string1 = 'Hello'
string2 = 'hello'

```
if string1.lower() == string2.lower():
    print "The strings are the same (case insensitive)"
else:
    print "The strings are not the same (case insensitive)"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use .capitalize()

```
answer = raw_input().capitalize()
```